# Set a css property with css depending on the number of items in a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible with CSS3 to format the children divs of a parent div with CSS only like:

1. When there are 3 divs set a property x on the div 1 and 2.
2. When there are 2 divs set a property x on div 1
3. When there is 1 div set no property x on div 1

Or do I have to use jquery for this dynamic logic?

Comment: showing some html markup would be clear to us that what you're asking actually....

Comment: and I don't think you can do with css only, you need to use jquery...

Comment: as you're not showing any effort to refresh your question, voting to close the question...

Comment: You need to use SASS or LESS to make operation on CSS before rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent div {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background: red;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
.parent div:last-child {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I think you can solve your problem with pure css.

Think of the last-child selector: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Style all childs the same, but apply something else to the last child.

so in the 3 div case, the third div will get the last-child style
in the 2 div case, the second child will get the last-child style etc..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with css. Here is a jQuery solution resulting in setting a class on the parent div (ex. 'has-3-children').

```
var yourDivElement = $('.your-div-class');

yourDivElement.addClass('has-' + yourDivElement.find('.children-div-class').length + '-children');
```

Then you can target and apply specific style according to that class.